# WMIC returns File Not Found when called from C++ or VB - command line works

Tags: c++, sql-server, wmi, wmic, wmi-query

Here is my code:

```
#define tcalloc(nCharacters) (TCHAR*)calloc(nCharacters,sizeof(TCHAR))
TCHAR *sCmdParam = tcalloc(1024);
StringCchCopy(sCmdParam, 1024,
    L"wmic.exe "
    "/NAMESPACE:\\\\root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ComputerManagement14 PATH ServerNetworkProtocol WHERE ProtocolName='Tcp' CALL SetEnable");
DWORD dwPID = 0;
DWORD dwExit = ExecCmdAndWait(sCmdParam, 120, SW_HIDE, &dwPID);
_tprintf(L"%u\n",dwExit);
free(sCmdParam);
_getchar_nolock();
return 0;
```

(ExecCmdAndWait simply calls CreateProcess)

If I run the wmic command from the command line at an administrator prompt it works properly.

What is different from running it from a compiled program?

It is running under domain administrator.

I tried also running it with "cmd.exe /c" in front of the 'wmic', but that gave the same result.

I also tried 'chdir' beforehand to c:\windows\syswow64\wbem and c:\windows\system32\wbem, both did not work.

And I tried calling from a quick VB6 program, which gave the same result.